# Data Table - Select Value of Column by Name From Another Column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with a number of columns containing values.  I have another column which defines which one of those columns whose value I need to select.  I am having trouble finding a way to do this.

Here is a simple example.

```
> d <- data.table(
     value.1 = c("one", "uno", "1"),
     value.2 = c("two", "dos", "2"),
     name.of.col = c("value.1","value.2","value.1"))

> d
   value.1 value.2 name.of.col
1:     one     two     value.1
2:     uno     dos     value.2
3:       1       2     value.1
```

I would like to add a column 'value.of.col' which contains the value of the column specified by 'name.of.col'.

```
> d
   value.1 value.2 name.of.col  value.of.col
1:     one     two     value.1  one
2:     uno     dos     value.2  dos
3:       1       2     value.1  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far.  The answers definitely work, but are very memory intensive.  Can anyone think of a good way to do this on a rather large data table?  The table I am working with is 700k rows, 132 columns and about 700MB.

Comment: does the second solution faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option:

```
d[ , value.of.col := diag(as.matrix(.SD)), .SDcols = d[ , name.of.col]]
> d
   value.1 value.2 name.of.col value.of.col
1:     one     two     value.1          one
2:     uno     dos     value.2          dos
3:       1       2     value.1            1
```

**EDIT** add a faster solution:

```
d[ , value.of.col :=
      melt(d,id.vars='name.of.col')[name.of.col==variable, value]]
```

Comment: +1 interesting use of column recycling and diag; you have a remarkable way of thinking about data; it would have never occurred to me to do it this way.

Comment: @BrodieG thanks. I add a new solution since the Op find the 2 solutions a little bit slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use matrix indexing to pull values from the first and second columns:

```
mx.idx <- d[, cbind(1:nrow(d), match(name.of.col, names(d)))]
d[, 
  value.of.col:=
    as.matrix(d[, 1:2])[mx.idx]
 ]
d
#    value.1 value.2 name.of.col value.of.col
# 1:     one     two     value.1          one
# 2:     uno     dos     value.2          dos
# 3:       1       2     value.1            1
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should be memory efficient and a little easier to read/follow.

```
for (i in unique(d[["name.of.col"]]))
    d[ name.of.col==i, value.of.col:=get(i) ]

d
   value.1 value.2 name.of.col value.of.col
1:     one     two     value.1          one
2:     uno     dos     value.2          dos
3:       1       2     value.1            1
```